# Ruby on Rails: Best way to show big data report efficiently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, psql

I am implementing a report that shows the analysis of quite a large set of data. The process includes joins and filtering on 4 database tables that themselves have around a million records on average. The complete processing and page rendering was taking around two minutes. I have improved this time to around 1 minute 35 seconds by optimizing my queries and applying indexing to the database.

Considering we cannot further optimize the queries, what are the possible solutions to improve the process speed that are usually used in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: How often does the data change? Is this something that you need to access "live" or "on demand" each time the page is requested?

Comment: Since you think you reached the limit of your optimizations, now you can proceed to getting bigger/more hardware.

Comment: Also, you can pre-calculate it in the background and the page would just show prepared data.

Comment: @craig.kaminsky the data will update on a frequent basis. Actually, it's report of my activity on account. So if I perform another task, the report should show updated stats.

Comment: Hard to say without code. Have you considered setting up a worker to process the data and storing the results in a table? How up-to-date do the results have to be? If real-time is the expectation, there may not be much more you can do.

Comment: @NickM Thanks. Would diving the process in different ajax calls do any help. Right now its processing on page rendering

Comment: @H_Z I was headed down the same road as NickM ... using a worker to process the data in the background and store it in a table (or materialized view). But, if it has to refreshed quite frequently, that can be tough. It may be worth looking at PG's MatViews, however, if you have some data that is more static than others.

Comment: Should I consider denormalizing my database a bit, to avoid some joins?

Comment: @H_Z that would be cheating. According to your question the queries cannot be optimized any further.

Comment: Well, I said queries, not the database structure. So denormalization would be an option for you right?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could move generating report to some background job? You have 2 options here: 
1. Generate after some action/cron job (e.g. project finished -> generate report) 
2. Have a nice button (request report) and then display nice message to user that you are going to email him a link to the report (or even you could display it on frontend after processing is finished).

I once was doing something similar and we were storing full html on S3 after generating report. Caching just the data was not enough - the amount of the data was so big that generating HTML was taking quite some time.